# Proxy redirect in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I have an OS X server running Apache, serving `www.mydomain.be`

I also have Jira running, standalone on `www.mydomain.be:8080`, and I would like to be able to access Jira via `jira.mydomain.be`.

In order to achieve this I added:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} jira.mydomain.be
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When surfing to `jira.mydomain.com` it redirects me but doesn't use the proxy. That's why I get `http://localhost:8080` in my address bar...

Suggestions?

I appended the above to the default site config under `/etc/apache2/sites`.

Comment: Why don't you just put Jira into it's own virtual host jira.mydomain.be?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use rewrite rules to proxy; just use the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` in a specific `NameVirtualHost` to proxy to the Jira instance.

Example off the top of my head:

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
 ServerName jira.mydomain.be

 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can u give an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
 ServerAdmin root@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 ServerName jira.mydomain.be

 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```